# MonoGame deltaTime isn't the same in Draw function as in Update function

Tags: monogame

In the Update function `gameTime.elapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` always gives me **0.01666666667** which is the deltaTime value for 60 FPS, no matter if the FPS is 30 it always shows me **0.01666666667** but the Draw function on the other hand shows **0.03333333333** if the FPS is 30.

Is this a bug or is this how it is meant to be? Should I just create a variable called deltaTime and make it equal to `gameTime.elapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` in the Draw function? Maybe this is a problem on Macs only

**(I'm on a mac and I'm using Xamarin Studio MonoMac to build the project)**

Comment: Shiro my mac can handle 60FPS the 30 fps thing was just an example

Comment: Shiro I understand now, Thank you. Just post that as an answer and I'll accept that answer

Comment: This tutorial explains it in a bit more detail: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/06/15/MonoGame-Tutorial-Creating-an-Application.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the `Update()` to be called as frequent as `Draw()`. Your `Draw()` method is generally called the same or less times than your `Update()`, because games are usually not CPU intense but rather GPU. So locking on 30FPS is normal (or even 15 or 7,5). However, there are probably problems with your code's efficiency, or your mac hardware is really bad, to not be able to handle 60FPS.

The reason that `Update()` being called more times than `Draw()` is acceptable in games, is because even though the visuals doesn't feel smooth, the game still runs at a higher frame rate, so the input you give, gets processed inside your game. So, it feels like the gameplay is the same, but you just don't see as many frames as you would hope to see.

This is why you need to keep in mind that `Draw()` should not change your game's variables or game's logic. This should only be done in the `Update()` method.